# {Multiple items} Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

[Screenshot placed here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f41kk.png)

I am using WordPress woo commerce, and when i increase the quantity of the product it display the title and SKU as **{Multiple items}** instead of product title and SKU, I have tried to find out the issue what is causing this but didn't find?

Comment: Seems like some third party API is adding the Order fee. Disable woocommerce plugin/extension (if any) and then check the issue.

Comment: And when i change the quantity of the product, it doesn't display the actual title and SKU. It display tittle and SKU as  (multiple items)

Comment: Please add some screenshots with the details in the question or share a link if you can.

Comment: I am trying to add screenshot but i am unable to do that.

Comment: @SamiAhmedSiddiqui Can you please tell me when i increase the product quantity, why it says multiple items in place of title of the product?

Comment: Not sure BUT this is not the default WooCommerce Layout. Are you customizing the layout or using some plugin for that?

Comment: This is not the default WooCommerce behavior. You are definitely using some plugin which is causing this or your own customization.

Comment: I am not sure why this is happening :( Did you see the screenshot? How to figure out?

Comment: I can not tell you this by just seeing the screenshot, you need to provide more details.